# Model use in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Im trying to either set the value of a variable to @Model.IsPublic which is a boolean value. In my javascript/jquery i have this.

```
 var pub=@Model.IsPublic
```

when i put a semicolon to finish the line it gives me an error. Might be a dumb question. but how can i set a variable to the models value

Comment: What? Are you talking about some Microsoft technology? Rails?

Comment: microsoft c# mvc jquery

Comment: Then you should put the correct tags. I see that @tereško fixed it for you.

Comment: and possibly Razor. In any case retagging required

Comment: @tereško I'm an ASP MVC user and I completely agree with you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because when converting `bool` to `string` ASP MVC uses uppercase. Javascript expects lowercase. What you are effectively doing right now is this:

```
var pub = True; // = error (unless you have an entity called 'True' - which I hope you don't)
```

What you need to do is this:

```
var pub = @Model.IsPublic.ToString().ToLower() // = var pub = true|false;
```

Alternatively, if you want to create the javascript variable as a string, you simply need to wrap the Model value in quotes:

```
var pub = "@Model.IsPublic";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var pub='@Model.IsPublic';
</script>
```